# getting an error : NoSuchMethodError: invalid member on null: 'length' in flutter web

Tags: flutter, web

I am using AnimatedSize fade to switch between two screens. When I switch from screen 2 to screen 1,  I get the error.
[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lglVz.png)

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Container(
  child: ScopedModelDescendant<Screen>(builder: (_, child, model) {
    return AnimatedSizeAndFade(
      vsync: this,
      child: model.showScreen ? AddBrand() : DemoTableLatestNew(),
      fadeDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
      sizeDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 600),
    );
 
  }),
);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Issue was not on this 
issue is in pages that you are navigating 
your using .length property on null value instead of string and list

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Y.B. Vamsidhar Reddy for pushing me in the right direction. I was getting the error because the ResultsDataSource object was empty and i was trying to get its length.